# Unique solution for circuits in Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, applications

A standard application of Linear Algebra is circuits and Kirchhoff's Laws. Does anyone know of a proof of uniqueness of a solution of a system given by these laws? There are many, many examples, but little theory regarding why there is always a unique solution.

For reference (Wikipedia)

- At any node (junction) in an electrical circuit, the sum of currents flowing into that node is equal to the sum of currents flowing out of that node
- The algebraic sum of the products of the resistances of the conductors and the currents in them in a closed loop is equal to the total emf available in that loop.

My thoughts are as follows:
Initially these laws setup two systems $Ax = 0$ and $Bx= b$, respectively. If there are $n$ nodes and m currents, then $A$ is a $n \times m$ matrix. If there are l loops in the circuit, then $B$ is a $l \times m$ matrix. I tried to work with the augmented matrix 
$$  \left[\begin{matrix}  A \\B\end{matrix} \right|\left.\begin{matrix}0\\b\end{matrix}\right]$$
But I see no reason why this always has a unique solution.

Comment: @NoChance that's not true; the equations need to be *independent* and *consistent*.

Comment: I would recommend looking at Gilbert Strang's Introduction to Linear Algebra if you have it on hand; he does look at Kirchhoff's laws in this way.  I don't remember if he proves uniqueness, though.

Comment: If it's not in there, you might need some results about "incidence matrices" from graph theory (at least, that would save you some work).

Comment: This also seems like it would be a fundamental result in the theory of [flow networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_network)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, you are correct. My statement was incomplete. Corrected now to state: If a system of equations has the same number of variables as equations, and the equations are independent and consistent and a determinant exists, then the solution will be unique.

Comment: You can't even be sure there is a solution -- suppose, for example, you short the two terminals of an EMF; then the resulting system of equations has no solution.

Comment: And if you have negative resistances, then solutions are not necessarily _unique_ either -- so a proof of uniqueness will need to depend on properties of order, not just on $\mathbb R$ being a field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a statement that works for your purposes (*proposition 9.4*) presented in [Markov Chains and Mixing Times (Levin, Peres, Wilmer)](http://pages.uoregon.edu/dlevin/MARKOV/markovmixing.pdf) that you can follow by reading pages 115-118.

Perhaps there are other, better references for you purpose, but this is the first that comes to mind.

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm looking for.  Thank you.